# Issue after importing private key to MultiBit

Tags: transactions, private-key, multibit, import

I followed another question here and imported my address from Bitcoin-QT to Multibit.
The reason why I did so was because I had received some BTC but in Bitcoin-QT it was taking years to download the blockchain. So I simply took the private key and imported in Multibit.

Now even after Multibit imports it successfully, the BTC I had received to the address do not show up. I have confirmed from blockchain.info and other sources, the transacton does exist.

ALSO, I have set correct date of the transaction in the import file during import.

Please advise what's wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: The date should be the date the key was created...maybe you've got it set wrong, try setting it back to a few days before (instead of the day of, to avoid timezone complexities) its first transaction.

Answer (score 2):

Set the date in the import file to the date the key was created (date and time are in UTC, not local time).  Then do Tools -> Reset block chain and transactions.  This will cause MultiBit to rescan the block chain from the earliest key creation time.  It should then show your transactions.

Answer (score 1):

"I have set correct date of the transaction in the import file during import" - I don't think you need to do this.

I believe the date is not the date of the transaction, but the date the wallet was created.

Try importing the private key again without changing the date.